# Compare two array of objects and filter out non matches to create new array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, compare, put

I am performing two `GET requests`. One to my database and one from an API.

I have two arrays of objects. In the array from my database, it will contain player data with some of their 'Active' statuses set to `true` or `false` (I am building a feature on the front end of my application that allows the user to control whether someone is active or not). In the array from the API, it will also contain player data but ALL of their 'Active' statuses are set to `true` by default and this data is pulled every 24 hours and it is sent to my database via a `PUT request` and overwrites all data.

Objective: If the 'Active' status is set to false in the array from the database, I want to ignore those objects in the array from the API and only update the database with the `'Active': true` players.

Here is an example of what would be in my database:

```
[{
    "PlayerID": 12345,
    "Team": "ABC",
    "FirstName": "Patrick",
    "LastName": "Star",
    "Position": "RB",
    "Active": false,
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "PlayerID": 67890,
    "Team": "DEF",
    "FirstName": "Spongebob",
    "LastName": "Squarepants",
    "Position": "WR",
    "Active": true,
    "__v": 0
}]
```

Here is an example from the API. Notice that Patrick Star's 'Active' status is true:

```
[{
    "PlayerID": 12345,
    "Team": "ABC",
    "FirstName": "Patrick",
    "LastName": "Star",
    "Position": "RB",
    "Active": true,
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "PlayerID": 67890,
    "Team": "DEF",
    "FirstName": "Spongebob",
    "LastName": "Squarepants",
    "Position": "WR",
    "Active": true,
    "__v": 0
}]
```

I want to compare these two arrays and return a new array with the players that are active (in this case Spongebob Squarepants). That way the players who are `'Active': false` are not affected in the database. I was thinking I can use the 'PlayerID' as a reference to help discern which players are active or not and filter from there. But I am stuck - any help is appreciated!

**EDIT - Here is my function this is to be implemented into:**

```
function getPlayers() {
  const APIplayersURL = "someURL";
  const DBoffensivePlayersURL = "http://localhost:4000/api/offensiveplayers";

  axios.get(DBoffensivePlayersURL).then((res) => {
    const inactivePlayers = res.data;

    // Filter out all of the active players
    const dbArr = inactivePlayers.filter(
      players =>
        players.Active === false
    );
    
    axios.get(APIplayersURL).then((res) => {
      const players = res.data;

      // Filter out all players except for QB, RB and WR
      const offensivePlayers = players.filter(
        players =>
          players.Position === "QB" ||
          players.Position === "RB" ||
          players.Position === "WR"
      );
      
      // Give me all active QBs, RBs, and WRs
      const apiArr = offensivePlayers.filter(
        offensivePlayers =>
          offensivePlayers.Status === "Active"
      );
  
      const result = dbArr.filter(
        (obj) => obj.Active && apiArr.some((o) => o.PlayerID === obj.PlayerID)
      );
      
      console.log(result);

      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": "x-auth-token",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
      };
  
        axios
          .put("http://localhost:4000/api/offensiveplayers", result, config)
          .then((res) => console.log(res))
          .catch((err) => console.error(err));
        console.log("Players updated successfully");
      });
  });
}

// Runs the getPlayers every 24 hours
setInterval(getPlayers, 86400000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the filter method to remove objects/values that don't return true.

```js
const players = [{
    PlayerID: 12345,
    Team: "ABC",
    FirstName: "Patrick",
    LastName: "Star",
    Position: "RB",
    Active: false,
    __v: 0
},
{
    PlayerID: 67890,
    Team: "DEF",
    FirstName: "Spongebob",
    LastName: "Squarepants",
    Position: "WR",
    Active: true,
    __v: 0
}];

const online = players.filter(player => player?.Active);

console.log(online);
```

Now if you want to `ignore` the users who are offline in the DB then you can use the id to check too.

```js
const playersDB = [{
    PlayerID: 12345,
    Team: "ABC",
    FirstName: "Patrick",
    LastName: "Star",
    Position: "RB",
    Active: false,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    PlayerID: 67890,
    Team: "DEF",
    FirstName: "Spongebob",
    LastName: "Squarepants",
    Position: "WR",
    Active: true,
    __v: 0
  }
];

const playersAPI = [{
    PlayerID: 12345,
    Team: "ABC",
    FirstName: "Patrick",
    LastName: "Star",
    Position: "RB",
    Active: true,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    PlayerID: 67890,
    Team: "DEF",
    FirstName: "Spongebob",
    LastName: "Squarepants",
    Position: "WR",
    Active: true,
    __v: 0
  }
];

const online = playersAPI.filter(player => {
  const copy = playersDB.filter(p => p.PlayerID == player.PlayerID);
  if(!copy.length) return false;
  return copy[0].Active;
})
console.log(online)
```

Comment: This will only filter the objects whose `Active` status is `true`, But you are not checking that it also exists in the array that comes from `API`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) here to filter out the objects that exist in `apiArr` and the same object with `PlayerID`'s `Active` status is `true`

```
dbArr.filter((obj) => obj.Active && apiArr.some((o) => o.PlayerID === obj.PlayerID));
```

```js
const dbArr = [
  {
    PlayerID: 12345,
    Team: "ABC",
    FirstName: "Patrick",
    LastName: "Star",
    Position: "RB",
    Active: false,
    __v: 0,
  },
  {
    PlayerID: 67890,
    Team: "DEF",
    FirstName: "Spongebob",
    LastName: "Squarepants",
    Position: "WR",
    Active: true,
    __v: 0,
  },
];

const apiArr = [
  {
    PlayerID: 12345,
    Team: "ABC",
    FirstName: "Patrick",
    LastName: "Star",
    Position: "RB",
    Active: true,
    __v: 0,
  },
  {
    PlayerID: 67890,
    Team: "DEF",
    FirstName: "Spongebob",
    LastName: "Squarepants",
    Position: "WR",
    Active: true,
    __v: 0,
  },
];

const result = dbArr.filter(
  (obj) => obj.Active && apiArr.some((o) => o.PlayerID === obj.PlayerID)
);


console.log(result);
```

Comment: You could speed up execution by taking advantage of short-circuiting in the filter condition since there is no reason to do the `.some` if `obj.Active` is false.

Comment: It didn't occur to me. That is a fine piece of optimization. Thanks for suggestion @StevenB.

Comment: @decpk Thank you tons for the response! So I implemented this into my code but it is returning an empty array :/ I edited my question to include my function. Perhaps you can see something I am missing.